# How can I source variables from a .bat file into a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I'm replacing parts of a .bat script with PowerShell. Configuration for the batch files is done via files that `set` appropriate environment variables. I'm looking for a way to load those variable values into the `.ps1` script, without modifying the `.bat` files (as they are also used in other places.

An example `.bat` looks as follows:

```
set VAR_ONE=some_value
set VAR_TWO=/other-value
```

In a batch script, I'd just `CALL` the configuration file and the variables would be available. I've tried both dot-sourcing (`. filename.bat`) and calling (`& filename.bat`) the configuration files from PowerShell, neither of those makes the variables visible. Tried accessing them with both with `$VAR_ONE` and `$env:VAR_ONE` syntax.

What would be a good way to load such configuration file without modifying it's format on disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd parse them (just skip all lines that don't start with `set` and split them with first `=` character. You can do it from o small C# cmdlet or directly with a small PowerShell script:

```
CMD /c "batchFile.bat && set" | .{process{
    if ($_ -match '^([^=]+)=(.*)') {
        Set-Variable $matches[1] $matches[2]
    }
}}
```

I have this code and I'm sure it comes from somewhere but credits have been lost, I suppose it comes from [Power Shell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) for an `Invoke-Batch` script.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx), it has a `Invoke-BatchFile` that does this.  I use with the Visual Studio vcvarsall.bat file to configure my PowerShell session to use the Visual Studio tools.

Comment: This is really the better answer as it allows for sourcing variables from any batch file, even one that has logic or calls into other files.

Answer (score 7):

The preferred option would be to change the configuration to a `.ps1` file and change the variable definitions to PowerShell syntax:

```
$VAR_ONE = 'some_value'
$VAR_TWO = '/other-value'
```

Then you'll be able to dot-source the file:

```
. filename.ps1
```

If you want to stick with the format you currently have, you'll have to parse the values, e.g. like this:

```
Select-String '^set ([^=]*)=(.*)' .\filename.bat | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value $_.Matches.Groups[2].Value
}
```

**Note:** The above won't work in PowerShell versions prior to v3. A v2-compatible version would look like this:

```
Select-String '^set ([^=]*)=(.*)' .\filename.bat | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Matches
} | ForEach-Object {
    Set-Variable $_.Groups[1].Value $_.Groups[2].Value
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that via a Batch file that first `call` the configuration file and *then* execute the PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the .bat is called `test.bat`, define `testps.ps1`:

```
$lines = cat "test.bat"
$output = @{};

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $bits = $line.Split("=");
    $name = $bits[0].Split(" ")[1];
    $val = $bits[1];
    $output[$name] = $val
}

return $output
```

Then the result is something like:

```
C:\temp> .\testps.ps1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
VAR_TWO                        /other-value
VAR_ONE                        some_value


C:\temp> $x = .\testps.ps1
C:\temp> $x

Name                           Value
----                           -----
VAR_TWO                        /other-value
VAR_ONE                        some_value


C:\temp> $x["VAR_ONE"]
some_value
```

There is probably a nicer way of doing the splits (will edit if I find it)

Answer (score 0):

- **Calling a batch file from PowerShell of necessity executes the batch file in a *child process***, given that a `cmd.exe` child process must be launched to execute it.
- **Whatever environment variables are set in a child process (batch file) are *not* seen by the calling process (PowerShell)**.

Therefore, a **workaround** is required:

```
cmd /c 'sample.cmd >NUL & SET' | 
  Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^PROMPT=' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Split the "<name>=<value>" line into the variable's name and value.
    $name, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
    # Define it as a process-level environment variable in PowerShell.
    Set-Content ENV:$name $value
  }
```

**Note**:

- This **recreates the batch-file environment variables *as environment variables* in PowerShell too**, using the [`Env:` PowerShell drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider#navigating-the-environment-drive) and `Set-Content`, thereby **ensuring that *external programs*** launched from your PowerShell session **see them too**.

  - By contrast, if [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) were used, it is *PowerShell-only* variables that would get created, which would only be seen by the current PowerShell session, not also by *child processes* (which external programs invariably run in) called from it.
- Executing `SET` (unconditionally after the batch-file call, via `&`) prints all then-current environment-variable definitions as `<name>=<value>` pairs.

  - `cmd.exe` also defines a `PROMPT` environment variable, which isn't relevant to PowerShell or other processes, so it is filtered out above.
- Via the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call, `$name, $value = $_ -split '=', 2` then splits each `<name>=<value>` pair into its constituent parts.
- **Assumptions**:

  - A fundamental prerequisite is that the target batch file *must not use `setlocal`* (as that would limit the scope of the variables to that batch file and the subsequent `SET` command wouldn't see them); that said, batch files whose express purpose is to set environment variables *for the caller* by design do not.
  - The assumption is that sole intent of invoking the batch file is to capture the environment variables that are set by the batch file; therefore,  the latter's *output* - if any - is *discarded* (`>NUL`), which simplifies parsing of the output.
  - Also, it is assumed that it isn't necessary to propagate *removal* of environment variables by the batch file.
  - If either or both of the latter two assumptions do not hold, you can find solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77112783/45375).