# PowerShell - fetching env variables after running a bat/cmd file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, environment-variables

I want to run a cmd file from powershell and retreive one set variable by that cmd file

my script returns a null/empty variable

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c 'my.cmd'" -Wait
$envVariable = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("my-variable", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
Write-Host "Environment Variable Value: $envVariable"
```

**the .cmd file contains lines like this**

```
set my-variable=2.6.4.6
```

how can I get that value from powershell ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Change to .bat extension instead of .cmd.

Comment: We have no idea what method you are using in that `my.cmd` to define a variable named `my-variable`. Generaaly however variables are localized to the `cmd.exe` instance within which they were defined. Given that, as soon as the first line has completed, that variable is unlikely to exist any more.

Comment: As a side note, you should not use `start-process` to run `cmd.exe` with the batch file as an argument, or the batch file, `my.cmd` directly.

Comment: @Compo yes I clearly stated the content of the .cmd file

Comment: You showed only some, and there may have been more code which made that a global, rather that just a local, variable. If there isn't, my first comment applies. The variable is no longer defined as soon as the first line has completed.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to understand - WHY is this necessary? If you want to set an environment variable, you can do this directly in powershell using `$env:Variable = 'Value'` Secondly, if you set an environment variable, you will not be able to use it in the current session until you reboot or refresh. You can read about refresh methods [here](https://thecategorizer.com/windows/how-to-refresh-environment-variables-in-windows/)

Comment: @jdweng, the choice of filename extension cannot possibly be expected to make a difference here - please consider deleting your comment to avoid confusion. (On a general note, `.bat` is to be _avoided_, as it changes the way certain internal (built-in) commands set the error level (exit code) for the worse - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148991/45375) for details).

Comment: @mklement0 : You are obsoletely wrong.  In both a cmd and PS window just typing the bat file name will run the script.  If you use cmd as extension you need to include the cmd or an invoke to get it to run.

Comment: @jdweng, no, `.cmd` files execute just fine directly and without extension from PowerShell, given that `.CMD`, just like `.BAT`,  is a default entry in `$env:PATHEXT`. What's frustrating is that you could have trivially verified this yourself instead of continuing to cause pointless distractions. Furthermore, even if what you're saying _were_ right - it obviously isn't - it would contribute nothing to solving the OP's problem; it would at best be an _aside_ which - without labeling it as such - causes confusion.

Comment: @pf12345678910, after belatedly realizing that your question is a duplicate, I decided to enhance the answer here to also support propagation of _removal_ of environment variables by the batch file (though that may rarely occur in practice). The simpler user case of simply propagating _new an updated_ environment variables can be achieved with a simpler solution that doesn't require before-and-after comparisons - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241115/45375).

Answer (score 2):

The **problem**:

- Use of [`[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable) would only work if your batch created *persistent* environment variables, i.e. those stored in the registry, e.g. via [`setx.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx).
- By contrast, `cmd.exe`'s internal `SET` command creates *process-scoped* environment variables, i.e. they are defined for the *current process only*.
- Because PowerShell of necessity runs a batch file (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`) in a *child process* (implicitly via `cmd.exe`), it has no way of querying the process-level environment variables created by a batch file: by the time the call returns, the batch-file process has exited, and its process-specific environment variables no longer exist.

---

A **potential solution**:

*Assuming that* your batch file does *not* use `SETLOCAL` before `SET`ting its environment variables - which would be the case if its purpose is to set environment variables for the hosting *`cmd.exe`*  session - you can use the following approach:

- Call the batch file via the `cmd.exe` CLI (`cmd /c`) and follow the invocation with a `SET` command in isolation, which lists all process-level environment variables after execution of the batch file.
- You can capture and compare this list to the process-level environment variables that *PowerShell* sees, which tells you which variables were added or updated, or even removed.

  - Note:

    - The following supports not just *added* and *updated* variables, but also propagates *removal* of environment variables performed by the batch file - hence the need for a [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)-based solution.
    - If supporting removal isn't necessary, a simpler solution is possible - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77241115/45375).

```bash
# Get the current list of env. vars. and their values, in the same
# format that cmd.exe's SET command produces.
$envVarsBefore =
  Get-ChildItem Env: | ForEach-Object { '{0}={1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Value }

# Synchronously execute the batch file and call SET from the same cmd.exe
# session to list all process-level env. vars.
# NOTE: 
#  * For simplicity, the batch file's own output is *discarded* (>NUL)
#    See the notes below this code if you want to pass it through.
#  * "PROMPT" is excluded, as it is only relevant to cmd.exe
$envVarsAfter =
  cmd /c 'my.cmd >NUL & SET' | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch '^PROMPT=' } 

# Now compare the two lists and define the variables in PowerShell
# that were added or updated by the batch file, and undefine (remove)
# those that were removed.
Compare-Object -PassThru $envVarsBefore $envVarsAfter | 
  ForEach-Object {
    # Variable was added or updated
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {
      # Split the "<name>=<value>" line into the variable's name and value.
      $name, $value = $_ -split '=', 2
      # Define it as a process-level environment variable in PowerShell.
      Set-Content Env:$name $value
    }
    # Variable was removed
    else { # $_.SideIndicator -eq '<='
      $name = ($_ -split '=', 2)[0]
      # Remove the variable
      Remove-Item Env:$name
    }
  }
```

Note:

- The above *discards* the batch file's own (stdout) output, under the assumption that it isn't of interest, which also simplifies processing. If you want that output to be *passed through* (or, if you adapt the code below accordingly to *capture it separately*), use the following snippet in lieu of the single `$envVarsAfter = ...` statement above:

  ```bash
  # Synchronously execute the batch file and call SET from the same cmd.exe
  # session to list all process-level env. vars.
  # For robustness, a GUID is used to separate the batch file's own output from
  # that of the SET command.
  # NOTE: "PROMPT" is excluded, as it is only relevant to cmd.exe
  $envVarsAfter = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]] @()
  $guid = (New-Guid).Guid; $guidFound = $false
  cmd /c "my.cmd & echo $guid& SET" |  # Note: NO SPACE after $guid.
    Where-Object {
      if ($guidFound) {
        # A line resulting from the SET command, add it to the list.
        if ($_ -match '^PROMPT=') { return } # Ignore the "PROMPT" variable
        $envVarsAfter.Add($_)
      } else {
        if ($_ -eq $guid) { $guidFound = $true; return } # The separator line.
        # A line output by the batch file itself.
        $_ # Pass it through.
      }
    }
  ```