# How to use `Invoke-BatchFile` in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, powershell, batch-file

I am trying to use [`Invoke-BatchFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080301/136285) from my Dockerfile. Here are the last lines of my Dockerfile:

```
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN ls '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"'
RUN Invoke-BatchFile '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"'
RUN cl /?
```

This gives me:

```
Step 51/53 : RUN ls '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"'
 ---> Running in d570af1a90e7


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
    Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/31/2024   8:24 AM          11526 VsDevCmd.bat


Removing intermediate container d570af1a90e7
 ---> 1810da031e12
Step 52/53 : RUN Invoke-BatchFile '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"'
 ---> Running in 2fdd038fb728
Removing intermediate container 2fdd038fb728
 ---> 77836a8ab3d9
Step 53/53 : RUN cl /?
 ---> Running in a4c8aecd383d
cl : The term 'cl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:76
+ ... nPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; cl /?
+                                                                     ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cl:String) [], ParentContainsEr
   rorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; cl /?' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Now if I try manually the same steps:

```
> docker run -it my_tag powershell.exe
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> Invoke-BatchFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"
PS C:\> cl /?
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33135 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
[...]
```

I must be missing something very obvious, but I do not see the typo here. Anyone see it ?

Comment: The first obvious typo is that you are using the incorrect path separators for Windows., ```\```, not `/`.

Comment: This problem has no relation with the `batch-file` tag. You should remove it and review what the tags you use in your question means...

Comment: My question is about loading variables from a batch-file. The tag `batch-file` seems pretty accurate IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Each `RUN` instruction runs in its own shell process.
- Therefore, the in-process environment variables that `Invoke-BatchFile` sets   only exist in (the child process created by) the very same `RUN` call.
- It follows that you must perform any calls that rely on these environment variables *as part of the same `RUN` call*.

```bash
# Note the '; cl /?' at the end.
RUN Invoke-BatchFile '"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat"'; cl /?
```